# How to display image from a url href in an excel cell

Tags: html, image, excel

I am processing several rows of data in an Excel application. Some of the cells contain image tags. Instead of showing the image tag strings (e.g. `<a href="#'><img src="/image.jpg" /><a>`). I want to be able to display the actual image in the worksheet cell, and also add a reference so that when the link is clicked, the user navigates to the link in the anchor tag.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are the image files in the same folder as the Excel worksheet? If not, where are they?

Comment: @barrowc: they are image resources (e.g. <a href="#'><img src="/image.jpg" /><a>), so they reside on the remote server specified in the src attribute of the img tag.